# Segfault: Dijkstra's implementation

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, dijkstra

Can someone help me determine why I'm getting a segmentation fault? I think it has to do with the way I'm allocating memory for my 2D and 1D vectors in main, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Is it perhaps some behaviour of the resize function that I'm not accounting for?

```
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void Dijkstra(vector<vector<int>> &G, int src) {
  deque<bool> visited(G.size(), false);
  vector<int> dist(G.size(),numeric_limits<int>::max());
  queue<int> q;

  dist[src] = 0;
  q.emplace(src);
  while (!q.empty()) {
    int cur = q.front();
    for(int i = 0; i< G.size(); i++) {
      if (!visited[i] && G[cur][i]) {
        q.emplace(i);
        dist[i] = min(dist[i], G[cur][i] + dist[cur]);
      }

    }
    visited[cur] = true;
    q.pop();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < G.size(); i++){
    if (dist[i] == numeric_limits<int>::max())
    dist[i] = -1;
    cout << dist[i] << "\n";
  }
 cout << "\n";
}



 int main() {
  int V, E, i , j, wt;
  cin >> V >> E;
  vector <vector <int> > G (V, vector <int> (V));


 for (int k = 0; k < E; ++k){ 
      cin >> i >> j >> wt;
      G[i][j] = wt;
      G[j][i] = wt; 
  }  

 Dijkstra(G, 0);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never set the size of `G`, so `G[i]` is out of bounds for *any* `i`. Why did you comment out `G.resize(V)`?

Comment: Even when I uncomment it, I'm getting a segmentation fault. I was trying to debug by commenting it out. Thank you, I've edited the post to include that line.

Comment: Use your debugger. Find out the line where the crash happens. Contemplate for a while. Do you need that line?

Comment: What is your input to the program? What is the values of `V` and `E`? Could `E` be larger than `V`? And in the reading-loop, the values you read for `i` and `j` can never be equal to or larger than `V`? Or negative? Perhaps you should check that?

Comment: You do `G[j][i] = 0;` before you've resized the `j`th vector. Just build the whole 2D vector as something like `vector< vector<int> > G (i, vector<int> (j, 0));` …

Comment: And you don't really need that initialization loop, all you need is `vector<vector<int>> G(V, vector<int>(V));` That defines *and* initializes all `int` elements to zero.

Comment: OK, I got the wrong variable(s) for the size >.< thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Will Crawford, after replacing the loop with your suggested line, I'm now getting a SIGABRT (3) message. Fortunately, the segmentation fault has been fixed, however.

Comment: You should try replacing it with @some-programmer-dude's version, I messed up with the `i` and `j` in there. Put `V` for both. `abort` is most likely out-of-memory, and would make sense if `i` and `j` (uninitialised at that point) were used to size the allocations.

Comment: Even after updating my code with @Someprogrammerdude's recommendations, I'm getting a segmentation fault (SIGSEGV).
EDIT: I've updated the original post with my current code for easy reference.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the input data? And / or add some debugging statements :)

Comment: I managed to fix it using your suggestions. But it turns out that I had misinterpreted the problem, so I'm now facing a different challenge, trying to determine how to work with vector <vector <pair <int, int> > >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this bit of code:

```
 G.resize(V);
  for (i = 0; i < V; ++i){
    G[i].resize(V);
    for (j = 0; j < V; ++j){
        G[i][j] = 0;
        G[j][i] = 0;
    }
  }
```

you're assigning to `G[j][i]` before you've resized `G[j]`, so the elements don’t exist yet.

As I tried to suggest, and @some-programmer-dude suggested more accurately, you should just have:

```
vector< vector<int> > G( V, vector<int> (G, 0) );
```

I thought the `, 0` was needed, he doesn’t, he’s probably right :o)

---

Just as a style issue, I'd suggest passing `V` into the `Dijkstra` function, or putting

```
const int V = G.size();
```

at the top, and use it instead of referring to `G.size()` everywhere.